# Duplicate field issue in form view odoo

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have create one field in **stock.quant.package** model.

```
tracking_ref=fields.Char("Tracking Ref")
```

This field is used in two separate modules and I am not able to give module dependency because both are separate modules.

> It may be possible that both modules are installed in same database or it may
>   be possible that in some database only one module is installed.
>
> Due to that reason i  have create same field & view in both modules.
>
> But now issue is that if both modules are installed then field is
>   available two times in the form view.

Is there any possibility that if we install both modules then field will visible only one time in form view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it is the best solution. Just try:

1. Create a new Module, say `module_common`
2. Put all common fields and functions in new module `module_common`
3. Make this module dependent of another two modules.

Ex: `module_a` depends `module_common` and `module_common` depends `module_common`.

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I agree with you because this field is needed in two module you should create a module that this two modules depends on. good and KbiR